# data conjunction in perl not working

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I am not able to denormalize the data for columns.How can I denormalize it.?  I have the below input

```
FieldA,FieldB,FieldC

bc,A1,A

bc,A2,A

bc,Z,Z

bc1,A,A

bc1,Z1,Z

bc1,Z2,Z

bc2,A1,A

bc2,A2,A

bc2,Z1,Z

bc2,Z2,Z
```

Required output as below

```
FieldA,FieldB,FieldC

bc,A1#A2,Z

bc1,A,Z1#Z2

bc2,A1#A2,Z1#Z2
```

I tried using push function, but it is not working. Please help in solving this.

```
my @aArray;

my @zArray;

while(<FILE_HANDLER>){

    chomp($_);

    @arr = split(/,/$_);

    $bc_name = $arr[0];

    $end = $arr[1];

    if($end eq $end_temp){

        push @aArray, $end;

    }else{

        push @zArray,$end;

    }

    $end_temp = $end;

}
```

Comment: You need to use hashes instead array.

Comment: Please review and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have code yet, Stack Overflow is not the right place for your question.

Comment: have added the code in the question

Comment: I've just improved the formatting of your question. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in the future. This included adding indentation to your code. Code is always easier to understand with clear indentation.

Comment: Please pardon. I shall adhere to it from next time. In this requirement, I need to group based on character 'A' or 'Z' .

Comment: @Dave : I am a beginner to perl. I am trying out programs. But I'm very happy that you have replied. [ I have been asked to go through "Data Munging with Perl" as well to learn perl]. Need to prepare more.

Comment: @tester: I hope the person who recommended "Data Munging with Perl" to you, pointed out that [it's now available online for free](https://datamungingwithperl.com/).

Answer (score 1):

use hashes for this kind of situations, use `bc,bc1,bc2` values as keys and concatenate the values with existing hashes.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my %h;
scalar <DATA>; #removing first line
while (<DATA>)
{
    chomp;
    my ($l,$r) = split(",");
    $h{$l} .= "$r ";

}

print "$_ $h{$_}\n" foreach (keys %h)


__DATA__
FieldA,FieldB
bc,A1
bc,A2
bc,Z
bc1,A
bc1,Z1
bc1,Z2
bc2,A1
bc2,A2
bc2,Z1
bc2,Z2
```

---

There is several problems in your script,

First thing is you should use `use warnings` and `use strict` in your every program.

Problem in you split function you have missed `,`. And this kind of situation use hashes, because if we need an array, some more logic we need to do.

---

If you are using default variable(`$_`), use the bellow code instead yours,

`chomp($_);` You can write as `chomp;`

`@arr = split(/,/$_);` you can write as `@arr = split(/,/);`

Comment: Code did not give correct result

Comment: @tester what is giving.???